Learning python and struggling with 'no module named' issue in VS Code
I feel like I'm missing some groundwork/basics on how to ensure the pip installs /module loading is setup to run correctly and wanted to ask for some guidance. Here is a specific example:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\atfle\Documents\VSCode Files\Python Strategies\.venv\webpage_to_pdf_and_python.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pdfkit
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfkit'
PS C:\Users\atfle\Documents\VSCode Files\Python Strategies> pip install pdfkit
Requirement already satisfied: pdfkit in c:\users\atfle\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (1.0.0)

I've got that exact file path in the requirement satisfied line added to System Variables PATH (I'm on Windows) and still no luck here. Any guidance would be appreciated.
I am trying to run python files but can't find consistency with modules I've installed and used previously in VS code.

Is VSCode running the script in the same interpreter/virtualenv as you are running pip?

You have to activate your virtual environment, then start/run your applications with that environment. Look for activate.bat in c:\Users\atfle\Documents\VSCode Files\Python Strategies\.venv\bin. I don't actually have a Windows environment to test this.

did you checked that you've activated your virtual environment?.

I believe so. I've got 'venv' 3.12 interpreter in the bottom right on vscode to show that it is running.

I just switched to conda environment and it ran! I think that while I solved this specific issue, I still need to learn the basics on this part. Any suggestions for resources to help me build the fundamentals correctly on running the right environment/interperter/PATH considerations? Thanks for answers.

Check your python interpreter. This was usually caused by incorrect python interpreter which didn't involve the python packages you need.

Check your current python environment, hover the terminal like this:
If you have Global it environment it should show you like this:
Global Environment
and if it's Local it should be like this: Local Environment
Now see if the current interpreter for python is the same as the one your installing your pdfkit package.
For windows

Press CTRL + Shift + P
Select Python interpreter
Choose the interpreter you've currently installed your pdfkit package in. From the given information I think it's Global.


Great, thank you! I swapped to  conda and it worked but I still need to learn the basics of this process better. Any guidance to resources on PATH/module installs/environments would be much appreciated.

Nice, feel free to ask me anything

Hi Drew Fleming, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)
